# Code for finding the files numbers missing in a folder

Tags: java, file

I need to identify the file numbers which are missing in a folder.

I have retrieved the files names by using the code below :

```
File folder = new File(FILE_PATH);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
    } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
    }
 }
```

But now after retrieving i need to find which are the file number which are missing from a file range of 1-1976 both included.

Comment: Sort by file name and compare them by incrementing.

Comment: So your files are named 1, 2, ...?

Answer (score 2):

If you need just the filenames, you may use `list()` method. After you get all the filenames with this method, you can just check the presence of the specified filenames, like:

```
File parent = ...
String prefix = "xxx_", suffix = ".txt"; // for example

Set<String> files = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(parent.list()));

// or, as suggested by @JulienLopez:

String pattern = Pattern.quote(prefix) + "\\d+" + Pattern.quote(suffix);
Set<String> files = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(parent.list((dir, file) -> file.matches(pattern))));

for (int i = 1; i <= 1976; ++i) { // actually constant should be used
    if (!files.contains(prefix + i + suffix)) {
        System.out.format("File #%d doesn't exist%n", i);
    }
}
```

But if you really need to check, that the file is not, for example, the directory, there's one more way to do it, by just creating the `File`s for every `i` and checking its existence:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1976; ++i) {
    File file = new File(parent, prefix + i + suffix);

    if (!file.isFile()) {
        System.out.format("File #%d doesn't exist or is directory%n", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. But you need to know the prefix and suffix (and it has to be unique), and if you do would it not be better to use `list(FilenameFilter)` instead of `list()` to keep only the files that matches "xxx_[0-9]+.txt" ?

Comment: @JulienLopez yep, you're right, I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Now if my file is in the format of abcde-1 _Transformed.xml . Then how should it be i am getting confused..?

Comment: And here does parent relates to the path where all the files are present?

Comment: @Rhino0419 use correct values of `prefix = "abcde-"` and `suffix = "_Transformed.xml"`. The `parent` is the directory, in which we get all the files.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure your structural of your file name , and what exactly on your mind with "both included". That is my idea,I hope it's a bit help for you.

```
String FILE_PREFIX= "your_file_prefix"; // Your file prefix. If your file is "logfile_on_20160121_0001" then the prefix is "logfile_on_20160121_"
int RANGE_MIN = 1;
int RANGE_MAX = 1976;
int fileList[] = new int[RANGE_MAX];
int directoryList[] = new int[RANGE_MAX];

// Quote your code with a bit modify from me
File folder = new File(FILE_PATH);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        // Added started
        String tempSplitedName[] = listOfFiles[i].split(FILE_PREFIX);
        if(tempSplitedName.length==2){
            int seq = Integer.parseInt(tempSplitedName[2]);
            if(seq>=RANGE_MIN && seq<=RANGE_MAX){
                fileList[seq] = 1;
            }
        }
        // Added ended
      } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        // Added started
        String tempSplitedName[] = listOfFiles[i].split(FILE_PREFIX);
        if(tempSplitedName.length==2){
            int seq = Integer.parseInt(tempSplitedName[2]);
            if(seq>=RANGE_MIN && seq<=RANGE_MAX){
                directoryList[seq] = 1;
            }
        }
        // Added ended
      }

// Now you count missing files/directory, which is equal 0
for (int i=RANGE_MIN; i<=RANGE_MAX; i++){
    if(fileList[i]==0) System.out.println("Missing file No." + i);
}
for (int i=RANGE_MIN; i<=RANGE_MAX; i++){
    if(directoryList[i]==0) System.out.println("Missing directory No." + i);
}
```

Comment: Do you know the KISS principle? (and how it applies to 2000 operations)

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: I'm sorry, but do you know what exactly different between my solution and your solution??? Try to read hard before comment and dishonour someone

Comment: Yes, I know, what is different. Your solution is longer, harder to read and (maybe) 3 times faster (1 ms instead of 3 ms)

Comment: @cuonghoang Well, his solution compiles and works for starters.

Comment: @JulienLopez: It's contrary in real, the code suggest by DmitryGinzburg is easier for read. The main different is about complexity of algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_class

Comment: @cuonghoang What's the point of decreased complexity for 2000 elements?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg: Keep your decision for your own, ok? I'm not a teacher. I'm answer, and hope it's useful for ask-er or someone else.If you don't like or don't understand, it's not my issue.